# Retrieving profile pictures of Facebook friends using facebook-sdk-unity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

We are converting to Facebook's unity SDK and running into an issue downloading the profile images of friends. We are getting this error:

error getting user picture Failed downloading https://graph.facebook.com/#USERIDHER#/picture?type=square?access_token=#OURTOKENISHERE#

The app has permission for friends_photos.  Is there another permission required for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it using the code from the sample Friends Smash Application, while using the default permissions.

1. Get the list of the friends by using the Graph API and astore it in m_friendData dictionary:

   FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(20).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetFbFriendsCallback);
2. Retrieving the friend avatar:

   FB.API(Util.GetPictureURL((string)m_friendData["id"], 96, 96), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, this.FriendPictureCallback);
3. The callback which process the answer:

`public void FriendPictureCallback(FBResult result)

```
{
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(result.Error);
        return;
    }

    friendAvatarImage.image = result.Texture;
}
```

`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just attempted to use the logic from Util.GetPictureURL, but I am getting the same problem.  Previously I've also building the URL myself, as well as actually getting it using web calls.  Something I didn't make clear previously -- this (and all the methods I've used) work fine within the Unity Editor -- it only fails when running the app in Facebook, that's why I think it's some sort of weird permissioning issue

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue for the SDK and is being worked on since March 5th, see this reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/364606280347510/